# Wait Notify pass NULL value Java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I'm trying to implement **wait()** and **notify()** inside my programs which have multithread (More than one thread notify and waiting).

**Problems**

Happens when two threads **wait()**, while I am **notify()**, both of them wake, which makes **Only one data, and both threads need to do**, and the result is **one threads win**, threads that lose will receive nothing **NULL**.

*This is my opinion only, might be different in your case, as it only happens in multithread environment*

**The Reason**

I might implement, **notify()** wrong, etc, I might not know, And it only happens like **20 Times Running, One Time Error**.

**Code**

```
//Single Threads

/*
 As seen here I am using single threads, and 
 if there is error, Depot Enter will shows error, 
 if no error means there is a data
*/

 bus = (Bus) ((LinkedList<?>) Shop.ListBusRamp).poll();
 System.out.println("Depot Enter: " + bus.getBusName());

/*
 In here I want to pass the value into another Linked List
 As earlier there is a value that I just poll.
 I can offer here and pass the value, no NULL occurred yet.    
*/

 ((LinkedList<Bus>) ListBusDepot).offer(bus);

 synchronized (ListBusDepot) {
     ListBusDepot.notify();
 }
```

As seen here I want to pass the value from **ListBusRamp** into **ListBusDepot**, as seen here no NULL occured yet, everything is good.

```
//MULTI THREADS (2 THREADS TO BE EXACT)

/*
  Here I want to wait for the data passed by notify
  After I got the data, I want to show it.

  As for why I check of Cleaners < 2?
  I create so that NOT ALL can enter, only when size is 2
*/

synchronized (ListBusDepot) {
    while (ListBusDepot.size() == 0) {
        try {
            ListBusDepot.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //VALUE MUST NOT NULL IF REACHES HERE

    bus = (Bus) ((LinkedList<?>) Shop.ListBusDepot).peek();
    if (counter.getBus_Cur_Cleaners() < 2) {
        counter.remBus_Cur_Depot();
        counter.addBus_Cur_Mechanics();

        //Here is the problem, while accessing data, it will show NULL
        System.out.println("Mechanics Earlier: " + bus.getBusName() + " fixed by" + name);

        bus = (Bus) ((LinkedList<?>) Shop.ListBusDepot).poll();
    }
}
```

As seen here the NULL is occurred, and how to prevent it, all I want is **if it is still null (empty), don't exit the loop while wait**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Happens when two threads wait(), while I am notify(), both of them
>   wake

No, only one will wake. `notifyAll` will wake up both.

---

You are synchonizing on `ListBusDepot`

```
while (ListBusDepot.size() == 0)
```

but try to take from `Shop.ListBusDepot`

```
bus = (Bus) ((LinkedList<?>) Shop.ListBusDepot).peek();
```

that's why `bus` is null.

---

Consider using a [`BlockigQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html), it will handle the `wait` and `notify` for you, so you can just focus on your business logis.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Shop.ListBusDepot and ListBusDepot is the same, they all in shop class, yeah I would like to use `BlockingQueue`, but this is an academic purpose, I need to use the traditional method.

Comment: @JoesLie Then you might want to post the complete code. This code looks good.

Comment: Yeah it only occurs randomly, based on luck. which is terrible. So is there a way to check make sure if it is empty then can proceed. For the complete code, it is just the same step, poll notify from one list to another.

Comment: @JoesLie As far as I can see, your code can make sure `bus` is not `null`.